# How can pass the current song data to my audio_service handler from the search page in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a music player app and I am able to play music with **just_audio** but now I want to add some more features like a background player. notification music control etc using **audio_service** package but I don't how can I pass current music details to the audio handler class also I don't see any latest tutorial on it to how to pass data.

Please help as I am stuck for hours right now.

**I am not using any state management package.**

This is the code of my AudioPlayerHandler

```
class AudioPlayerHandler extends BaseAudioHandler with SeekHandler {
  static final _item = MediaItem(
    id: podcastLink,
    album: "Science Friday",
    title: "A Salute To Head-Scratching Science",
    artist: "Science Friday and WNYC Studios",
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 4464000),
    artUri: Uri.parse(
        'https://media.wnyc.org/i/1400/1400/l/80/1/ScienceFriday_WNYCStudios_1400.jpg'),
  );

  

  final _player = AudioPlayer();

  AudioPlayerHandler() {
    _player.playbackEventStream.map(_transformEvent).pipe(playbackState);

    mediaItem.add(_item);

    _player.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(_item.id)));
  }

  @override
  Future<void> play() => _player.play();

  @override
  Future<void> pause() => _player.pause();

  @override
  Future<void> seek(Duration position) => _player.seek(position);

  @override
  Future<void> stop() => _player.stop();

  PlaybackState _transformEvent(PlaybackEvent event) {
    return PlaybackState(
      controls: [
        MediaControl.rewind,
        if (_player.playing) MediaControl.pause else MediaControl.play,
        MediaControl.stop,
        MediaControl.fastForward,
      ],
      systemActions: const {
        MediaAction.seek,
        MediaAction.seekForward,
        MediaAction.seekBackward,
      },
      androidCompactActionIndices: const [0, 1, 3],
      processingState: const {
        ProcessingState.idle: AudioProcessingState.idle,
        ProcessingState.loading: AudioProcessingState.loading,
        ProcessingState.buffering: AudioProcessingState.buffering,
        ProcessingState.ready: AudioProcessingState.ready,
        ProcessingState.completed: AudioProcessingState.completed,
      }[_player.processingState]!,
      playing: _player.playing,
      updatePosition: _player.position,
      bufferedPosition: _player.bufferedPosition,
      speed: _player.speed,
      queueIndex: event.currentIndex,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can reference this https://github.com/yringler/inside-app/tree/master/just_audio_handlers  , as author said : A few composable implementations of @ryanheise 's audio_service AudioHandler. There are:
The base handler, which works with just_audio

Comment: @chunhunghan let me check it out

Comment: @chunhunghan can you add that code url here I am not able to find that

Comment: In https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service , Can I make use of other plugins within the audio handler?  ...There are also plugins like just_audio_handlers that provide default implementations of AudioHandler to make your job easier...

Comment: @chunhunghan yeah sure

Comment: @chunhunghan i added my AudioPlayerHandler Code

Comment: @chunhunghan do you get anything, bro? sorry to disturb you

Answer (score 0):

first af all if you want add some new features and complicity to your player you definitly should use some state management package. because player is something that will definitly change states in diferent ways.

secondly, if your question is only about how to pass data in class, then you shouldn’t invent a bicycle, the simplest and most common way is through a constructor(or you should formulate the question more precisely). If somewhere you have search page and data from it for player, then you pass this data to the AudioPlayerHandler, e.g.:

```
YourDataClass(
        id: podcastLink,
        album: "Science Friday",
        title: "A Salute To Head-Scratching Science",
        artist: "Science Friday and WNYC Studios",
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 4464000),
        artUri: Uri.parse(
            'https://media.wnyc.org/i/1400/1400/l/80/1/ScienceFriday_WNYCStudios_1400.jpg'),
);
```

So:

```
const AudioPlayerHandler(YourDataClass data) {         
    _player.playbackEventStream.map(_transformEvent).pipe(playbackState);
        
    final _item = MediaItem(
        id: data.podcastLink,
        album: data.album,
        title: data.title,
        artist: data.artist,
        duration: duration,
        artUri: Uri.parse(data.artUri),
      );
      mediaItem.add(_item);
        
      _player.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(_item.id)));
}
```